# How to clear state when statesave page no longer exists in datatables?

Tags: datatables

My datatables is declared in this way:

```
"processing": true
,"serverSide": true
,"stateSave":true
,"stateDuration": 60*60*24
,"ajax":{
   "url":"/approval/search.json"
   ,"type":"post"
}
```

My code to clear state:

```
if(page doesn't exist){
  table.state.clear();
  table.draw()
}
```

I don't know how to tell if page doesn't exist. I've tried table.page.info() but the data it shows is the same whether the page has info or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After SO MUCH trial and error I finally succeeded with this:

```
,"fnDrawCallback":function(){
    if(table.row().data()===undefined){
        table.state.clear();
        location.href=url
    }
}
```

Comment: is this fnDrawCallback inside data table function?

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for newer versions of datatables:

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {
    let api = this.api();

    // fix pagination if saved page is empty
    if (api.page() > 0 && api.rows({page: 'current'}).count() === 0) {
        api.page('previous').state.save();
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

This will set the state to the previous page if the current does not exist, and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I may have used the previous answer and alter it. It work perfectly for me :

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {
    let api = this.api();
    var info = api.page.info();
    if (info.pages!=0 && (api.page() > 0 && api.rows({page: 'current'}).count() === 0)) {
        api.page('first').state.save();
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```